Make renderTable and renderPlot occupy the same horizontal space as renderDT
In Shiny, it seems like renderTable and renderPlot are constrained by a defined horizontal space (of 12 columns?), but renderDT is able to override this...
Given the following MWE:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)


test_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot"), width="100%"),
        DTOutput(ns("table"), width = "100%")
      ),
      fluidRow(column(width=8, div(tableOutput(ns("fasta1")), style = "font-family:Courier;")),
               column(width=8, div(tableOutput(ns("fasta2")), style = "font-family:Courier;"))
      )
    )
  )
}


test_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat)) +
      geom_point()
    })

    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(cbind(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,mtcars), options = list(pageLength = 10, sDom = '<"top">rt<"bottom">ip'), rownames = TRUE, class = "hover row-border order-column nowrap", selection = "none")
    })

    output$fasta1 <- renderTable({
      data.frame(fasta1="<pre>>fasta1<br>ACGATGCTAGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGCTGATCGTAGCTGATCGTAGTCGATGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTGATCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTAGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATCGTAGCTGACTGATGCTAGCGATCGATGCTAGC</pre>")
    }, bordered = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = identity)

    output$fasta2 <- renderTable({
      data.frame(fasta2="<pre>>fasta1<br>ACGATGCTAGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGCTGATCGTAGCTGATCGTAGTCGATGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTGATCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTAGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATCGTAGCTGACTGATGCTAGCGATCGATGCTAGC</pre>")
    }, bordered = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = identity)

  })
}

demoApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    test_ui("demo")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    test_server("demo")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

demoApp()

Would it be possible for me to have my 2 fasta sequences next to each other (instead of one below the other) in a way that they do not overlap? It is strange that renderDT can take all that horizontal space, but I still cannot place my sequences under it next to each other...
Likewise for the plot... is it possible that it takes the same 100% width as the table?
The code above produces the following:


You can get the two tables on one row by defining max width for each column at 6 and playing with print.xtable attributes (used by renderTable to display the table, see the docs) to modify the CSS style of the table:
in UI:
      fluidRow(column(width=6, div(tableOutput(ns("fasta1")), style = "font-family:Courier;")),
               column(width=6, div(tableOutput(ns("fasta2")), style = "font-family:Courier;"))
      )

in server:
   output$fasta1 <- renderTable({
      data.frame(fasta1="<pre>>fasta1<br>ACGATGCTAGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGCTGATCGTAGCTGATCGTAGTCGATGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTGATCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTAGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATCGTAGCTGACTGATGCTAGCGATCGATGCTAGC</pre>")
    }, width="100%", bordered = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = identity,  html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes",
                                                                                           "style='table-layout:fixed'"))
    
    output$fasta2 <- renderTable({
      data.frame(fasta2="<pre>>fasta1<br>ACGATGCTAGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGCTGATCGTAGCTGATCGTAGTCGATGCTGATGCTGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTGATCGATGCTAGTCGATGCTAGCTAGCTAGTCGATGCTAGTCGATCGTAGCTGACTGATGCTAGCGATCGATGCTAGC</pre>")
    }, width="100%", bordered = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = identity, html.table.attributes = getOption("xtable.html.table.attributes",
                                                                                              "style='table-layout:fixed'"))
    

We can avoid the table overflowing the div by setting table's width to 100% and using table-layout:fixed. With a small screen width, you'll get horizontal scrollbars in your sequence tables. On larger screen width, the sequences are fully displayed with no scrollbars.
